# Got the Bitcoin Wallet. How do I transfer money into it?

Tags: wallet

I've got active connections & there are blocks downloaded but I don't know what to do next. Presumably I need to transfer some money in there so I can buy bitcoins. But how?

Any suggestions gratefully relieved. 
Thanks.

Comment: There are currently development efforts in place to integrate the exchanges with the various wallets to make this process much easier in future. You may also want to look over http://lovebitcoins.org which offers practical advice about how to reach an exchange local to you.

Comment: Can anyone help me. I want to buy bit coins, but I need them to transfer to another wallet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible to buy bitcoins from inside the client. What you need to do is this:

- Find someone that you can buy bitcoins from. One way is to use an exchange, such as [Mt.Gox](http://www.mtgox.com), that let's you deposit USD (or some other currency) and then buy bitcoins.
- In the Bitcoin client (assuming you use the original client from bitcoin.org), get a Bitcoin address from the "Receive coins" tab ("New address..."). Using a new address for each transfer will increase your anonymity.
- Transfer the bitcoins you bought to your new Bitcoin address. If you use Mt.Gox you would use the "withdraw" option. The bitcoins will then show up in your client.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I did get the wallet from bitcoin.org and have got an address from the. I’ve been trying to get the bitcoins on Mt.Gox. I will try the ‘withdraw’ option on MtGox now. Thanks!

Comment: Mtgox.com seems to be now in Bankrupt. Any other proposals?

Comment: Do you have any proposals how to do the case in euros?